# UseEffect infinite loop with array of dependencies

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm having an issue with useEffect and useState. I'm trying to fill a state with data from an api, but it results in an infinite loop, even if I use an array with dependencies. It works when I try to get a name. The problem occurs when I try to get an array or an object.

Here the code:

```
      const id = props.match.params.id;
      const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({});
    
      useEffect(() => {
        let cancelRequest;
        axios
      .get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`, {
        cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken(
          (cancel) => (cancelRequest = cancel)
        ),
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setPokemon(res.data);
        console.log(pokemon);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`ERROR:: ${err.message}`);
      });
      return () => {
        cancelRequest();
     };
    }, [id, pokemon]);
```

Here a sample of data from the console:

```
{abilities: Array(2), base_experience: 64, forms: Array(1), game_indices: Array(20), height: 7, …}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have `pokemon` in deps, which means `useEffect` will be called on every change `pokemon`. Which happens when you are called `setPokemon` every `useEffect` with new ref. Leave only `[id]` in deps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the axios request inside the useEffect.

Create another function for this and use `useCallback`. For example:

```
const fetchPokemon = useCallback(() => {
 axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`)
   .then((res) => {
     setPokemon(res.data);
   })
   .catch(() => {}
}, [id])


useEffect(() => {
 fetchPokemon()
}, [fetchPokemon])
```

If you pass in `pokemon` into the dependency array, it will update every single time you call `setPokemon` since the pokemon update aka, you have an infinte loop.